# Cache entire HTML response in Laravel 5

Tags: php, caching, laravel-5, middleware

I am trying to cache entire response using middleware

**Steps i followed**

**Generated two middleware**

- AfterCacheMiddleware
- BeforeCacheMiddleware

**With in BeforeCacheMiddleware:**

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{            
        $key = $request->url();
        if(Cache::has($key)) return Cache::get($key);
        return $next($request);
}
```

**With in AfterCacheMiddleware**

```
public function handle ($request, Closure $next)
{       
    $response = $next($request);
    $key = $request->url();       
    if (!Cache::has($key)) Cache::put($key, $response->getContent(), 60);
    return $response;
}
```

**Registered middleware in $routeMiddleware array of kernal.php**

```
'cacheafter' => 'App\Http\Middleware\AfterCacheMiddleware',
'cachebefore' => 'App\Http\Middleware\BeforeCacheMiddleware',
```

*With in routes.php i am calling this dummy routes like this*

```
Route::get('middle', ['middleware' => 'cachebefore', 'cacheafter', function()
{
    echo "From route";
}]);
```

**Issue:**

only **cachebefore** middleware is getting called. cacheafter is not getting called at all

Can anyone suggest what i am missing here ?

Answer (score 12):

I found this question while I was looking for solution myself. I am aware that there is the Flatten package which does this caching, but I couldn't find  nice examples on how to do this by myself. The solution attempt in this question contains ideas that were useful for my own solution, although I chose to go with a single middleware only.

Although the question is old and asker probably doesn't need the answer anymore, I will share my solution here as I feel that SO (and internet) lacks this caching sample  for Laravel 5. I will try to explain as much as I can, but for most benefit you should be familiar with [Routing](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/routing), [Caching](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/cache) and [Middlewaring](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/middleware) in Laravel 5. So here goes the solution:

### Middleware

Create a middleware, those are usually placed in `app/Http/Middleware` folder and I will call the file `CachePage.php`

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Guard;
use Cache;

class CachePage
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        $key = $request->fullUrl();  //key for caching/retrieving the response value

        if (Cache::has($key))  //If it's cached...
            return response(Cache::get($key));   //... return the value from cache and we're done.

        $response = $next($request);  //If it wasn't cached, execute the request and grab the response

        $cachingTime = 60;  //Let's cache it for 60 minutes
        Cache::put($key, $response->getContent(), $cachingTime);  //Cache response

        return $response;
    }
}
```

Change `$key` according to your needs... You have all the `$request` with all the parameters... Change `Cache::put($key, $value, $minutes)` to `Cache::forever($key, $value)` if you will clear the cache manually and don't want it to ever expire.

Using the URL as key for storing cache is usable in most cases, but one might think of something more appropriate for a certain project.

### Registering middleware

Register it in `app/Http/Kernel.php` by adding the middleware to `$routeMiddleware` array like this:

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
    /* ...  */
    /* Other middleware that you already have there */
    /* ... */
    'cachepage' => \App\Http\Middleware\CachePage::class,
];
```

Of course, you should change `\App\Http\Middleware\CachePage` if you placed it elsewhere or gave it another name. Also the key name `cachepage` is up to you - it will be used to invoke the middleware.

### Usage

In your `app/Http/routes.php` use the middleware just like `auth` or other middlewares, for example, you might make a route group for all the pages that should be cached:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'cachepage'], function () 
{
    Route::get('/', 'HomeController@home');
    Route::get('/contacts', 'SectionController@contacts');
});
```

Comment: `return Cache::get($key);` no longer seem to work in Laravel 5.3. Use `return response(Cache::get($key));` instead.

Comment: I used similar logic in my own caching package: https://github.com/GlaivePro/CachePage

Answer (score 0):

The list of middlewares has to be inside square brackets:

```
Route::get('middle', ['middleware' => ['cachebefore', 'cacheafter'], function()
{
    echo "From route";
}]);
```

Comment: This is the answer to question "why does my solution fail to call the second middleware?". I have added a complete solution that's different from askers attempt in a separate answer.